# Make a table by calculating the percentage for each ID

Tags: r

Here is my data:

```
ID      nb     value    
ID1     3       1  
ID1     3       0    
ID1     3       1.5 
ID2     2       12 
ID2     2       648 
ID3     4       7
ID3     4       0  
ID3     4       0 
ID3     4       7
ID4     2       146
ID4     2       3
```

`nb` show the number of `value` for each `ID`.

I want to get a table by calculating the percentage of `value==0`, `0<vlaue<6`, and `value>=6` for each ID, the expected result is:

```
ID      value=0    0<vlaue<6    value>=6
ID1        1/3         2/3         0
ID2         0           0          2/2
ID3        2/4          0          2/4
ID4         0          1/2         1/2
```

I tried `setDT(df)[, p1 := length(v==0)/.N, by = .(ID)]`but it's not work.

Hope to get your answer soon!

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. What have you tried that has not worked?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I tried `setDT(df)[, p1 := length(v==0)/.N, by = .(ID)]` but it's not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `cut` to create the group, and then try with `table` on a subset of columns ie. the 'ID' and 'grp' column.

```
tbl <- table(transform(df1, grp=cut(value, breaks=c(-Inf, 0, 6.0001, Inf), 
           labels=c('value=0', '0<value<6', 'value>=6')))[c(1,4)])
res <- prop.table(tbl,1)
res
 #       grp
 #ID      value=0 0<value<6  value>=6
 #  ID1 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.0000000
 #  ID2 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
 #  ID3 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000
 #  ID4 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
```

If you need as 'fractions'

```
 library(MASS)
 fractions(res)
 #    grp
 #ID    value=0 0<value<6 value>=6
 #    ID1 1/3     2/3         0     
 #    ID2   0       0         1     
 #    ID3 1/2       0       1/2     
 #    ID4   0     1/2       1/2
```

Or from the 'tbl', we can also `paste` to get the expected output as showed in the OP's post

```
 tbl[] <- ifelse(tbl==0, 0, paste0(tbl, '/', rowSums(tbl)))
 tbl
 #   grp
 #ID  value=0 0<value<6 value>=6
 # ID1 1/3     2/3       0       
 # ID2 0       0         2/2     
 # ID3 2/4     0         2/4     
 # ID4 0       1/2       1/2
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID2", "ID3", 
 "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID4", "ID4"), nb = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L), value = c(1, 0, 1.5, 12, 648, 7, 0, 
 0, 7, 146, 3)), .Names = c("ID", "nb", "value"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: @MamounBenghezal  I think it just needs some changing in the breaks.  I was only trying with the OP's example.

Comment: Why we need `[c(1,4)]`?

Comment: @velvetrock I am subsetting the dataset to include only the first and fourth column

Comment: @MamounBenghezal  I'm sorry, what is the problem in the labels?  It is what the OP asked for.

Comment: But if I have more than 4 IDs, such a 1000, I should change it to `[c(1,1000)]`

Comment: @velvetrock No, If you have a single ID column, there is no need to change.  Can you confirm whether there are values less than 0?

Comment: No, there is no value less than 0.

Comment: Actually, I've not understood why you did a subset which include only the first and fourth column? :(

Comment: @velvetrock  The `df2 <- transform(df1, grp=cut(value, breaks=c(-Inf, 0, 6.0001, Inf), 
           labels=c('value=0', '0<value<6', 'value>=6')))` adds a new column 'grp'.   We only need the 'ID' and the 'grp' column to get the `frequency`.  So, the 1st column in the dataset is 'ID' and 4th is 'grp'.  So, I subset the dataset.

Comment: Why it gives me the first and the forth row of `df2 <- transform(df1, grp=cut(value, breaks=c(-Inf, 0, 6.0001, Inf), labels=c('value=0', '0<value<6', 'value>=6'))) ` by using the [c(1,4)]

Comment: @velvetrock Probably, you are subsetting by rows. Try `df2[c(1,4)]`.  Also, I assume that your dataset is `data.frame` instead of `data.table`.  If you are using `data.table`, convert to `data.frame` with `setDF(df1)`.